# Linux: only allow outgoing connections to specific domains

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, whitelist, nftables

I have a CentOS server and only want to allow outgoing connections to specific domains. (allowlist) My thought was to have a DNS proxy which adds the allowed ips (only ipv4 needed) to nftable named sets. Is there an easy solution for this already?

Edit:
Alternatively I would create a script which would update the entries in /etc/hosts and nftables, but it seams a bit error-prone to me, if the server-ip changes.

Comment: You can filter with `ip(6) daddr DOMAIN`, at least this seemed to work for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a script which updates the entries in `/etc/hosts` and a set in nftables. It works well without problems, also I don't think it is an elegant solution.